# Formatting the border between lattice panels in R

Tags: r, lattice

When making a multi-panel plot in lattice, each panel is by default bordered by a black line. I would like to be able to adjust the color and width of these panel borders. Bonus points if you can show how to add a colored border around specific panel(s).

For instance, this code makes a plot with three panels, one for each unique value of df$gears. Each panel is bordered by a black line.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(mpg~hp|factor(gear), mtcars, layout=c(3,1), between=list(x=c(1))
   ,par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col="lightgray")))
```

This code almost does what I want. It changes the borders (and tick marks) of all panels to light gray. Is there a way to change the color of components independently (e.g., left and right axes)? Is there a way to address the formatting for each sub-panel independently?

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide a mockup?